# Core Data predicate to fetch based on two of relationship's properties

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two simple Entities:

```
Part {
    @NSManaged var states: Set<PartState>  
}

PartState {
    @NSManaged var date: Date
    @NSManaged var state: Int
}
```

I want to fetch those entities from `Part`, that newest `PartState` has `state == 1`.

I've tried to create `NSPredicate`:

- `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(states, $s, $s.date == max($s.date) AND $s.state == 1).@count > 0")`

  It looks like `max($.date)` checks all existing `PartState` entities, not just those belonging to a given `Part` and always returns 1 or 0 results.
- `NSPredicate(format: "ANY (states.state == 1 AND states.date == states.@max.date)")`

  Fails with: `Unable to parse the format string...`
- `NSPredicate(format: "ANY states.state == 1 AND ANY states.date == states.@max.date")`

  Returns all entities that have ever had state == 1 (which is what I would expect).

The only other solution that comes to my mind, is to have newestState property in Part but I still looking for some NSPredicate-based way.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch latest entry based on date using sort Descriptor
and apply predicate to fetch which has state == 1

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Part>.init(entityName: "Part")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "states.date", ascending: false)]

 let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "states.state = %@","1")
```

Comment: I think this will return me those parts that have ever had the state == 1. States property is Set<PartState> and contains history of state changes. I want fetch all parts with current (newest) state == 1.